# Postfix how to set up relaying

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta, qmail

I am new to Postfix.... used mostly qMail in the past. This is my config:

1. I have Postfix SMTP server set up on domain aaa.com
2. Emails should be sent with "From" and "Reply-to" headers for another domain bbb.com.
3. bbb.com is on a different dedicated server and not in the list of "mynetworks".

It all works fine, but I am getting "*SPF: HELO does not match SPF record (softfail)*" when testing emails for spam score. So, I need to add my aaa.com domain into the list of allowed relay hosts (rcmpthosts file for qmail).

How can I do this with Postfix? Should I add aaa.com to **relay_domains** or **relayhost**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check the dns records of aaa.com , the spf record does not contain the ip op your postix server, this is why you receive the SPF error.
Have a look at http://www.openspf.org/ & http://spfwizard.com/

Br,
E-raser